# Change large actionbar title font

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Is possible to change large actionbar title font?

I am using large bar like this:

```
 const actionBar = <ActionBar>this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement;

        actionBar.on("loaded", (args) => {
            if (actionBar.ios) {
                const navigationBar: UINavigationBar = actionBar.ios;
                const color = new Color("white");

                navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true;
                navigationBar.tintColor = color.ios;
                navigationBar.barTintColor = color.ios;

                navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = <any>{
                    [NSForegroundColorAttributeName]: color.ios
                };

                navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = <any>{
                    [NSForegroundColorAttributeName]: color.ios
                };
            }
        });
```

I have applied custom font to actionbar by CSS. But this change is not reflected in large bar. When I turn off large bar then title is in custom font.

Comment: I don't see any code related to font above, can you share the exact code you are trying for changing the font of action bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can change font styles by using a `FormattedString` tag inside your template element and added some `Span`s to get your formatting. [You can check de docs here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/formatted-string).

To do so from within the TS, try adding the following code:

```js
const format:FormattedString = new FormattedString();
const span:Span = new Span();
span.fontFamily = 'name-your-font';
```

...and then put `Span` inside the `FormattedString` and the `FormattedString` inside your `ActionBar`.

Hope it helps! If it doesn't, let me know!